# Not able to update a user whose status is "ActivationSent" or "Created" via REST API

Tags: docusignapi

Sometime back i was able to update users irrespective of whether they were active or not.

However now it seems that update only works for active users and doesn't work for users for which status is ActivationSent.

```
PUT https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/357938/users/bff36bfc-35cc-4dd3-8e23-af1bbebeec7c/profile HTTP/1.1
X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>foo</Username><Password>****</Password><IntegratorKey>key</IntegratorKey><SendOnBehalfOf>bff36bfc-35cc-4dd3-8e23-af1bbebeec7c</SendOnBehalfOf></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Host: demo.docusign.net
Content-Length: 83
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"userDetails":{"firstName":"donot","lastName":"delete","userName":"donot delete"}}

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 116
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 29 May 2014 01:30:38 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=7776000; includeSubDomains

{
"errorCode": "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
"message": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid."
}
```

The user status is marked as "Created".

```
"userName": "donot delete",
"userId": "bff36bfc-35cc-4dd3-8e23-af1bbebeec7c",
"userType": "CompanyUser",
"isAdmin": "False",
"userStatus": "Created",
"uri": "/users/bff36bfc-35cc-4dd3-8e23-af1bbebeec7c",
"email": "donotdelete@donotdelete.com",
"firstName": "donot",
"lastName": "delete",
```

Does that mean one cannot make updates/deletes on a user who has not activated their account via REST API?
This used to work sometime back via REST API and certainly still works via the UI.

Are there any known workarounds for this?

Thanks
Somesh

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect that the current behavior you descibe is 'by design'. The **Modify User Profile** API request must be authenticated by supplying the credentials of the User that the request attempts to modify (which you're attempting to accomplish by using **SendOnBehalfOf** in the **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header). But, a Member with status = **ActivationSent** technically isn't an active member of the account at that time, so I wouldn't expect them to be able to access DocuSign in any way -- i.e., neither via the API nor via the web console -- as long as their status = **ActivationSent**.

I would be curious though (as you are), as to how you could programmatically correct/update a member's name or other profile attribute between the time that you've created the Member (sent activation) and the time that the Member actually activates his/her membership account.  Seems like this would be a fairly common use case (i.e., to allow for correcting spelling of a member's name or email address, etc. if incorrectly specified during Member creation), but I'm not seeing an obvious way to accomplish it. Perhaps someone from DocuSign can chime in on this thread to provide further clarification.

Comment: Thanks! This scenario was definitely working around March, 2014  timeframe , so i wonder if this is a regression?

Comment: I saw someone adding a comment few days back suggesting this might be a bug and verify that at their end. I no longer see that comment so I am assuming it was deleted? Did anyone from docusign got a chance to test this scenario?

Comment: That comment was added by Andrew Wilson (DocuSign)...not sure why he's deleted the comment. I'd suggest you contact DocuSign support to follow up directly with them.

Comment: Would you know how one contacts support for API issues in DocuSign? The online documentation seem to point to this stackoverflow forum for any questions and I didn't find an obvious way to escalate further.

Comment: From their website: "For DocuSign product support, please email us at support@docusign.com or call us at 1.866.219.4318."  Be sure to explain your scenario -- i.e., you think you've encountered a bug with the API, someone from DocuSign (Andrew Wilson) seemed to confirm such via a Comment on your StackOverflow question -- but he later deleted the comment, so you're not sure where things stand. Expect them to ask you for detailed repro steps -- so be ready to provide that information.